# heightForRowAtIndexPath involves many cells

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I need to change dynamically the row of a cell. That's why I use selectedIndex variable to store the selected row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;

TarModel * tar = self.tarList[indexPath.row];

if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"detailCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}


// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = tar.way;

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cost: € %@",
                             tar.price];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"indexpath is %d", indexPath.row);
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    isSearching = YES;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

and then I change the height of my selected row with this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat height;

    if(selectedIndex == -1) {
        height = 44.0;
    }
    else if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        height = 88.0;
    }
    else {
        height = 44.0;
    }

    return height;
}
```

when I run this code and the first row is selected everything is ok, but if the second (only two rows in mytableview) is selected I get even all the next empty rows with the modified height. Where'I'm getting wrong?

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath is not called every time the user selects a row.

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj OP is reloading the UITableView when the user selects a row

Comment: Where is selectedIndex defined? You do not need two conditions that result in returning 44, just one.

Comment: @cicaletto79 I tried using your code and only the selected row gets the larger height (as you want). So, looks like there's something else other that the code snippet you've pasted that is messing this up.

Comment: It is not clear in your question whether you want to select multiple cells or just one at a time.

Comment: I need to select just one row at a time, and when selected it should have a larger height...

Comment: I suggest you mark a breakpoint in the heightForRowAtIndexPath.Then you can figure out why height value is edited.

Comment: @StevenJiang I debugged and noticed that the heightForRowAtIndexPAth is called only twice (I have only 2 rows).

Comment: @cicaletto79 Maybe you can check the value in 'else if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)'. Since the result turns to both of row became 88.

Comment: Please post proper code of this functionality cellforow method also and didselect method proper method.

Comment: And why are you calling deselect method in didselect method, it is not required, the row you select will automaically deselect previously selected row.

Comment: @iPhoneProgrammatically just edited the post including my cellforrow code. Also, I removed the unuseful deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

for the update height of cell dynamically you can use below code :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      if (indexPath.row == 1)
          selectedIndex = 150;
      else
          selectedIndex = 44;

      [tbl_news_list reloadData];
}
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return selectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: this code makes a larger height for all my rows (two rows populated and the others empty) if indexPath.row = 1. Normal height for all if indexPath.row = 0.

Comment: you can assign selectedIndex value according to your requirement I have just given to you idea.

Comment: sorry perhaps I cannot understand your code @Shubham. You use the selectedIndex variable to store the modified height, don't you? so I don't need to apply the row height change only to the second row (index = 1) as you typed.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
       return 44;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
       return 88;
    }
    else{
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` inside  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`   will once again reload  cells  on  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

It worked fine , i expanded clicked row in demo app.:)